# band pass filter on solar cell to detect laser

Tags: microcontroller, filter, solar-cell, signal-processing, dsp

my target is detecting a laser generated with 1k frequency using a solar cell, i'm using [this idea](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlyVThcNRE4) which is using a band pass filter on the solar cell to block the dc sun light and let me detect the laser, the problem is that i'm completely lost for how i would implement this in a circuit

i've calculated the RLC band pass filter to have 3kohm, .22h and .1uf, which is not bad to start with 
[image]

the solar panel i'm using is Mini Solar Panel 6V/250mA

but as i'm inexperienced in this field i'm kinda lost, so please either gimme answers or simple schematic

bunch of questions :
q1- is the filter going to remove the dc volt coming from the sun and only leaves me with analog signal of 1k frequency ? aka if the sun will gimme 5v and the laser effect will be 20mv then will the filter o/p be +-20mv square/sin wave ?
q2- i'm using microcontroller to read this input so how much current would that produce if i'm using the following schem.., do i need a resistor to limit the current and how would it affect the wave

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/80801/using-a-solar-panel-for-laser-light-detection

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I think it's okay. This contains specific design considerations and expands. I don't like the gimme answers part though.

Comment: I wish everyone who posted a crap video on youtub had to sit in here & answer all the duplicate questions that it spawns. In the end, user3761832, a pv cell IS NOT the best way to detect a laser in sunlight. A photoresistor, photodiode, or phototransistor, that is either tuned to the laser's wavelength, or has an optical filter that's tuned to the laser's wavelength is way better than a pv cell, and is less likely to be saturated beyond functioning by spurious light artifact. The 1KHz laser modulation helps with a small part of this, but when the "right" parts are _cheaper_, don't waste $$$.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do two passive RC's in series.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMh7PF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've made it a bit wide and sloppy... you can play with the capacitor values.  The first part is a high pass with a 1 ms time constant ~160 Hz, the second is a low pass with a 10 us time constant. ~16kHz.  You want to keep the second R big so it doesn't load the first stage.